# extraposed "it" with clause headed by "when"

Tags: extraposition

There was a question here today about extraposed "it" with clauses headed by "that" and by "when". Here's an analogous example:

> It was with a great sense of pride that Charlie learned his twelve-times table.
>
> It was with a great sense of pride when Charlie learned his twelve-times table.

The second example with **when** sounds ungrammatical. However, the following sounds grammatical, to my ear:

> When Charlie learned his twelve-times table, it was with a great sense of pride.

Why is it we can "manufacture" or "extract" a grammatical subject from the *when*-clause for anaphoric **it**  in a matrix clause that ends the sentence, but not for "dummy/expletive" **it** at the start of the sentence from the subordinate clause that ends the sentence?

Comment: I think it's unidiomatic rather than ungrammatical. We expect **It was... when...** to refer to the time when something happened.

Comment: **It was six o'clock when we finally finished the job** sounds right to me, but **It was with a sense of relief when we finally finished the job** doesn't.

Comment: But *When we finally finished the job it was with a sense of relief* does sound OK to you, right?

Comment: Yes, it does sound OK.